# Steps to generate a windows script to create user concurrency?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Question, what would the steps to write/create a windows (bash?) script that will allow me to create user concurrency of 3 or 4? Would I need to write a script that modifies the "config" file in the .snowsql folder and then run it from snowsql? Any guidance or high level steps would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each independent invocation of [`snowsql`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html) will create its own connection, so you can certainly fire them up in parallel `CMD` or `PowerShell` windows. If you also want to change the user or other aspects of each connection created, `snowsql` accepts [command-line parameters as overrides](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#connection-syntax) (such as `--username`) instead of only relying on the `config` file.

If your goal is to perform a load test of concurrency, a common approach is to use [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) with a [DB Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) using [Snowflake's JDBC Driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc.html). Alternatively, you can also use a multi-threaded Python script like the one presented in [this concurrency/scaling testing article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Putting-Snowflake-s-Automatic-Concurrency-Scaling-to-the-Test).